# PyQt6 Successfully Installs but cannot be imported

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyqt6

I donwloaded PyQt6 using `pip install pyqt6` and it had a bunch of errors so I uninstalled it and reinstalled it with `pip install pyqt6 --user` and the errors dissappeared. problem is trying to use it in VSCODe or any other ide doesn't work. When i write:
`from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction, QMenu, QMessageBox` VSCode gives me the error `Import "PyQt6.QtWidgets" could not be resolved.` Could someone walk me through what I may of done wrong please?

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip) help at all?

Comment: I don't use VSCode so I'm not sure, but, isn't that just a warning? Have you tried to run the code? Because an actual failed import should show `ImportError: No module named 'PyQt6'` or `ImportError: cannot import name <...>`. Those warnings are often caused by issues from the IDE configuration, but don't automatically mean that the program won't run.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in VSCode:

- On the lower right of the VSCode window you should see the language
  mode and version that VSCode is currently using. Something like "Python" *3.10.7*.
- If you **HOVER** over this text (like *3.10.7*), VSCODE will display the
  actual path used for that version.
- If you **CLICK** on the version, you can change the **LANGUAGE MODE** and **VERSION** that is being used by VSCode in the window while editing (and executing) Python code.  The language and version reflect the path to the library used.
- In my case when I looked, the version had changed to a beta version I'd mistakingly installed earlier (3.11.03b).  The version I was using when I installed PyQT6 was 3.10.7.
- When I changed the version back to 3.10.7, suddenly everything worked again.

In my case, I had been moving things around in migrating from PyQT5 to PyQT6 and was now using a different file folder for my migrated code.  I opened up a new VSCode Window and then my new PyQT6 folder, and I failed to notice that VSCode had chosen what it thought was the 'latest' version of the interpreter.